# Change DNS A records dynamically

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, vps, a-record, vds

For example, I'll buy domain name at godaddy.com. I'll configure it with 2 A records with IPs 123.0.0.1 and 123.0.0.2. 
*Is it possible to ping it for availability and change A records dynamically by some script?*

Comment: As far as I know, GoDaddy does not have an API that will let you change DNS-settings via a script. What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: I'm trying to cover some sever fails at least partly

Answer (score 3):

There are ways to do [dynamic updates](http://www.isc.org/software/bind/documentation/arm95) with [BIND](http://www.isc.org/software/bind).  But they are server-specific, and must be enabled and configured on the server.

You really need to be asking Godaddy what they support in this area.

Also note that dynamic DNS is a very poor way to do failover, as to be effective, it requires setting a very short TTL, which ends up wasting lots of bandwidth, and is generally annoying.

Answer (score 1):

by the sound of it, you have a dynamically assigned ip address from your ISP. You may want to move your DNS to an entity such as DynDNS.com and use a dynamic DNS client on one of your hosts to update your DNS when your dynamic ip address changes.

Comment: This. afraid.org is also a nice alternative. You can also create a CNAME record for your domain with GoDaddy and have it point to the DNS service so that it's always pointing to the right IP